# Automatically update outdated pip3 packages with bash scripts

Tags: bash, pip, updates

I have a bash script to automatically update pip3 packages:

It is one line script:

```
pip3 list --outdated | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs pip3 install --upgrade
```

and it has always worked.

Now (maybe after the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04) it is not working anymore apparently because of a wrong usage of `pip3 install`.

What is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like headers of the pip3 list are causing failure in installation of package.
You can trim those header lines by using tail.

```
pip3 list --outdated | cut -d' '  -f1 | tail -n+3 | xargs pip3 install --upgrade
```

tail -n+3 removes the header and boundary line which only gives package names to xargs.

Comment: It is working. some packages keep on having problem. I'll copy the new problems here.

Comment: @phd ```head -3``` will print the only lines which we are trimming using ```tail -n+3```